# Is it possible to auto mount entire truecrypt drive

Tags: disk-encryption

Truecrypt can easily automount if your drive is not entirely encrypted and your data is a standard file.  However I have my entire removable storage encrypted and so to the OS, it is seen as an unformated disk.  Is there anyway to automount said drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is usually possible in this way:**

- Mark the external drive's Truecrypt partition or drive as a "Favorite".
- Open the ["Favorite Volumes Organizer"](http://www.truecrypt.org/screenshots6).
- Check the option "Mount selected volume upon logon" for the Favorite'd encrypted partition or drive.

See the [FAQ, section "Can a volume be automatically mounted whenever I log on to Windows?"](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq)

However, keep in mind that if your external drive is connected via USB or Firewire, then it may change device path from time to time. This often happens if you connect the drive to another physical port, or you add other removable external drives to the system. In this case I think the auto-mount will fail, until you fix the Favorite setting.

**Edit @Yongke Bill Yu:** After the belated mention that Truecrypt isn't installed on the host computer, the only possibility is "Traveler Disk". That's basically a disk with an un-encrypted partition with an executable instance of Truecrypt.exe , and another partition which is encrypted. Within the above limitations, the [Traveler Disk can actually auto-mount drives via Windows' "autorun.inf"](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) format.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the case that the drive is connected via USB.  Besides, it would not work if the computer does not have TrueCrypt installed anyway.  I believe I have given up on this question.